# US postal search object defined error

Tags: vba, object, runtime

i'm fairly new to objects, i borrowed this code from stackoverflow and i keep getting the following error.

Run Time error 1004
object defined error
 my user and string are correct based on the example at the bottom. not sure what i need to change.

```
Sub get_correct_address()

    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim htm As Object

    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest%20USERID=""968APPRA1046"">" & _
                    "<Address>" & _
                    "<Address1></Address1>" & _
                    "<Address2>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(row, StrNumCol).value) + " " + Sheets("import").Cells(row, StrNamCol).value + " " + Sheets("import").Cells(row, StrTypCol).value & "</Address2>" & _
                    "<City>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(row, CityCol).value) & "</City>" & _
                    "<State>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(row, StateCol).value) & "</State>" & _
                    "<Zip5></Zip5>" & _
                    "<Zip4>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(row, ZipCol).value) & "</Zip4>" & _
                    "</Address>" & _
                    "</AddressValidateRequest>" & _
                    """, False"
        .send
        htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
    End With
    Debug.Print (qry)

    With htm.getelementbyid("comps-results")
        For x = 0 To .Rows.length - 1
            For y = 0 To .Rows(x).Cells.length - 1
                Sheets(1).Cells(x + 1, y + 1).value = .Rows(x).Cells(y).innertext
            Next y
        Next x
    End With

'http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest%20USERID="xxxxxxxxxxxx">

End Sub
```

Comment: First tip: tell us on which line the error occurs.

Comment: on the "get" line i get the erro

Answer (score 0):

The .Open syntax should be like .open Method, URL, Async which in your case should be .Open "GET", TheURL, False.

You have some additional """ at the end which makes the end of the URL as """, False"

Correct this to:

```
Dim TheURL As String
TheURL = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest%20USERID=""968APPRA1046"">" & _
                "<Address>" & _
                "<Address1></Address1>" & _
                "<Address2>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(Row, StrNumCol).Value) + " " + Sheets("import").Cells(Row, StrNamCol).Value + " " + Sheets("import").Cells(Row, StrTypCol).Value & "</Address2>" & _
                "<City>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(Row, CityCol).Value) & "</City>" & _
                "<State>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(Row, StateCol).Value) & "</State>" & _
                "<Zip5></Zip5>" & _
                "<Zip4>" & CStr(Sheets("import").Cells(Row, ZipCol).Value) & "</Zip4>" & _
                "</Address>" & _
                "</AddressValidateRequest>"  ' & _
                '          """, False"   ''' The last part has been commented out to correct the URL

    .Open "GET", TheURL, False
```

and the code should get executed, assuming that you are filling the other referenced variables like Row, StrNumCol etc and that rest of the code like `htm.getelementbyid("comps-results").Rows.Length` being referenced in your sample code point to correct parameters.